# Twilio Studio - Authentication Error with Request Body

Tags: twilio-studio

Good day.  I am using an HTTP Request in Twilio to trigger a second Twilio Studio flow.  I am getting an authentication error but I don't know how to structural place my info in the Request Body.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please include your call and the error you are receiving to get proper help

Comment: Thanks.  Here is the call that is within the Twilio Studio http request module.  From=%2B19803133174&To=%2B19803133174.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add your Twilio client SID and key to the headers of the HTTP widget, otherwise the call to the REST API of your flow will fail as you're seeing now.

Comment: Do you know how to do this, there does not seem to be that option.

Comment: Since you're triggering the flow from another flow using the HTTP widget, the safest (and easiest) route would be to create a simple Twilio function calling the other Flow API.  In that case you can use the HTTP widget in Studio Flow A to call the Twilio function which in turn will trigger Studio Flow B.  If you enable the function to include credentials you don't have to pass them along.  In addition, you should secure the function so that it can only be called internally and isn't exposed publicly. See https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions/invocation#context-object

Comment: Thank you for answering.  I was able to accomplish this using a function with got.